# Compile Error Syntax Error Vba

Tags: vba, excel

The script I have is written to run through a series of rows and remove every row if certain strings are not found in them. The error I am encountering is that when I run the script I get the error

> "Compile Error Syntax Error"

and the `Instr` line is highlighted as having the error.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        If InStr(.Cells(Lrow,"I").Value,"Removal") = 0 and _
           InStr(.Cells(Lrow,"J").Value,"removal") = 0 and _
           InStr(.Cells(Lrow,"J").Value,"removed") = 0 Then.Rows(Lrow).Delete

    Next Lrow

End With
```

If anyone knows why this is happening or has a solution it would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: What object are you using to start the `With` block?

Comment: The rest of your code, so we know what's what would help

Comment: Sorry about that I included the if statement it is embedded in

Comment: @ScottCraner - I looked at that too - but if you edit OPs post - it is formatted correctly - it's just that SO puts it all on one line

Comment: @GMalc Yes I need to find both those cases

Comment: Reformatted your question and code to show line breaks and now it's easier to see the syntax answer at the end of the line. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. After the edits done to your post you don't see the error. But I was able to copy the original code you posted. Your issue is the line breaks "_" used without breaking the line. The reason the "and" word was not capitalized automatically by the editor is because of that.

Your code:

```
If InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "I").Value, "Removal") = 0 and _ InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removal") = 0 and _ InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removed") = 0 Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete
```

You can either use a single line:

```
Sub Testing()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Select
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        If InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "I").Value, "Removal") = 0 And InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removal") = 0 And InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removed") = 0 Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete
        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

Or if you use line breaks "_" make sure to go to the next line.

```
Sub Testing()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Select
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        If InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "I").Value, "Removal") = 0 And _
            InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removal") = 0 And _
            InStr(.Cells(Lrow, "J").Value, "removed") = 0 Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete
        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've defined the WITH object correctly it looks like you are simply missing a space in

```
Then.Rows(Lrow).Delete
```

It should look like this

```
Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete
```